# RSS campaign with mailchimp for blogger

Tags: rss, blogger, mailchimp

in a RSS campaign with mailchimp for blogger I can't get the *|RSSITEM:CONTENT|* to show only part of the post. I t shoes it ALL. how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Go to Blogger.com » Settings » Other and change the option "Allow Blog Feed" to "Until Jump Break" or "Short".

**Option 2**

In you MailChimp campaign settings set a different blog feed URL:

```
your-blog-url.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/summary?redirect=false
```